# How to create a function based on CAST

Tags: postgresql

Due to some reasons, I want to create a function based on cast function.
It's just a wrap of cast.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert(in1 anyelement, in2 anyelement) 
RETURNS anyelement AS $func$
BEGIN
    execute $$ SELECT CAST(in2 AS in1) $$; 
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I executed the function, I got the error like the following:

```
select convert(float, 1);

ERROR:  column "float" does not exist
LINE 1: select convert(float, 1);
===============================================
```

How can I make the my custom function works

Comment: You need to pass the data type as a string: `select convert('float', 1)`

Comment: ["_Each position (either argument or return value) declared as anyelement is allowed to have any specific actual data type, but in any given call **they must all be the same actual type**._"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC). It seems that your idea is failed at this point.

Comment: Use `select 1::float` instead. Isn't this better?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, but I need to pass the "type" into the function, not the string of the type.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks. Yeah, so far I have no other ways to do it :(

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail (I guessing that you are trying to migrate from one DBMS to another). Perhaps there exists the least painful solution. Good luck.